# Promises - this.fileLoad.then is not a function

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde.

Estou tendo esse erro - this.fileLoad.then is not a function, alguem poderia por favor me explicar o motivo de isso estar ocorrendo?

```
fileLoad(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{

        let fileReader = new FileReader();

        let fieldFile = [...this.formID].find(element =>{

            if(element.type === "file"){

                return element.files;

            }
        });

        fileReader.onload = () =>{

            fileReader.result;
            resolve(fileReader);
        }

        fileReader.onerror = () =>{

            reject("erro");

        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fieldFile.files[0]);
    }

)};

this.fileLoad.then(    
        (content)=>{
            console.log(content);

        },
        (e)=>{

            console.log(e);

 })
```

> Uncaught TypeError: this.fileLoad.then is not a function
>       at userController.addUser (userController.js:76)
>       at userController.loadFiles (userController.js:57)
>       at HTMLDocument.document.addEventListener.event (userController.js:20)

Comment: Já tentou sem o **this**?

Comment: Obrigado encontrei o erro, esqueci de definir a chamada para uma function this.fileLoad.then - this.fileLoad.then();

Comment: Bruno, se puder, marque a pergunta como respondida amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa chamar a função com  parêntesis, this.fileLoad().then(...

Comment: Não precisa não man.